Taskbar visible on lock screen under Wayland after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1
I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04.1, and since then I've encountered a reproducible issue under Wayland that I believe is a security risk.
Whenever I lock the session (for example, by pressing CTRL+L), the taskbar remains visible on the lock screen. I can even hover over the individual apps with the mouse, and their preview windows appear. While I am still unable to interact with the applications themselves, I believe this violates the purpose of the lock screen, as no session information should be visible in this state.
Details:
  Ubuntu version: 24.04.1
  Display server: Wayland
  Desktop environment: GNOME 46.0
Steps to reproduce:

Lock the session using CTRL+L or via the top-right menu.
Observe that the taskbar remains visible.
Hover over the icons to see app previews (which should not be accessible).

Visible taskbar on lockscreen:

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a known fix or workaround? I'm considering reporting this as a bug, but I wanted to check if anyone has insights before doing so.
Thanks in advance for your help!
